# How can I filter out current directory ('.') in bash?

Tags: bash, files, scripting

I'm currently trying to write a little script to convert all the flac files to mp3 files. However, I ran into a bit of a problem when trying to set up recursion down into all my music folders - the script kept looping into the current directory (.)

Here's what I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash

#---
# flacToMp3: Converts FLAC files in my originalFLAC folder into mp3 files
#            and places them in an identical folder structure in my Music
#            folder.
#---

function enterDIR {
    for DIR in "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d)"; do #recurse into every directory below top-level directory
        if [ "$DIR" == "." ]; then  #avoid current directory infinite loop
            continue
        fi
        cd "$DIR/"
        enterDIR
    done

    createDirectory
    convertFLAC
}

function createDirectory {
    #recreate directory structure in Music folder
    curDir="$pwd"
    newDir=${curDir/originalFLAC/Music}
    mkdir -p $newDir
}

function convertFLAC {
    #convert each flac file in current directory into an mp3 file
    for FILE in "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)"; do #loop through all regular (non-directory) files in current directory
        if [ "${FILE: -5}" == ".flac" ]; then #if FILE has extension .flac
            ffmpeg -i "$FILE" -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 "${FILE%.*}.mp3"; #convert to .mp3
            mv -u "${FILE%.*}.mp3" $newDir
        else #copy all other files to new directory as-is
            cp -ur "$FILE" $newDir
        fi
    done
}

enterDIR
```

This script is pretty clunky, since I only just started dipping into Bash. The problem (or at least where I think it is) comes from the `if [ "$DIR" == "." ]; then` line - looking at my output when running the script, it doesn't seem to filter it.

**How do I filter out (ignore) the current directory?**

Comment: One = for [ ...

Comment: Can't you use something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.flac"`?

Comment: You'll want to read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 -- don't use `for` to iterate over *lines*.

Comment: I think `find . -type f -name "*.flac"` would suffice. Let find delve into your directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter it in `find` by using `-mindepth` option. Like this:

```
function enterDIR {
    find . -mindepth 1-maxdepth 1 -type d | while read DIR ; 
    do 
        #recurse into every directory below top-level directory
        cd "$DIR/"
        enterDIR
    done

    createDirectory
    convertFLAC
}
```

---

But the whole script doesn't look like a good solution.

If I understand your idea correct, you want to walk through the whole directory tree, create there new directory, convert flac to mp3 if any and copy all non-flac files to a new dir. I would do that this way:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type -d -exec mkdir -p {}/originalFLAC/Music \+
find . -type f -iname "*.flac" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 {}.mp3 \;
find . -type f ! -iname "*.flac" | while read file ; do cp -v "$file" "$(dirname "$file")"/originalFLAC/Music/ ; done
```

Comment: +1 for giving the actual solution: using find for what it's for and not recurse manually into the directories.

Comment: Please demonstrate good practices: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: I realize that, but you could take that one extra step

Comment: well, maybe you're right. thx for comment. answer is updated.

Comment: Wow, I guess I really missed/misunderstood a lot of things in the find man file. What's the function of `!` in the last line?

Comment: `!` means `not`. therefore  `find . -type f ! -iname "*.flac"` means find all files with name not matching to `.flac` (i before name means case insensitive)

Comment: While I'm leaving it accepted because you technically answered my question, I would like to note that (because apparently I didn't test the results of the script earlier) yours didn't actually work. It fails on the copying section - `cp: cannot create regular file ‘./originalFLAC/Music/’: No such file or directory` So I'm not sure you're doing the string substitution correctly, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

try replacing this

```
for DIR in "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d)"
```

with this

```
for DIR in "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep -v "\.$")"
```

`.` is interpreted as "any" single character in regex. So it has to be escaped with backslash. Also since all your lines will start with a dot character, you will need to find the line that has the dot and only the dot. Hence the end of line character `$`.

at this point, you should not need the `if` block below:

```
if [ "$DIR" == "." ]; then  #avoid current directory infinite loop
    continue
fi
```

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name .`